# Disable SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS with Pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I want to disable Disable SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS with Pagination. For that purpose, i am using the following code from [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS](https://wpartisan.me/tutorials/wordpress-database-queries-speed-sql_calc_found_rows) but due to that code pagination not working. How i do this or how to improve below code?

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'oz_optimized_get_posts' ) ):
function oz_optimized_get_posts() {
    global $wp_query, $wpdb;

    $wp_query->query_vars['no_found_rows'] = 1;
    $wp_query->found_posts = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')" );
    $wp_query->found_posts = apply_filters_ref_array( 'found_posts', array( $wp_query->found_posts, &$wp_query ) );

    $posts_per_page = ( ! empty( $wp_query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] ) ? $wp_query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] : get_option( 'posts_per_page' ) );
    $wp_query->max_num_pages = ceil( $wp_query->found_posts / $posts_per_page );

    return $wp_query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'oz_optimized_get_posts', 100 );
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Edwar D author of the post ["WordPress: SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, why it’s slow and what to do about it"](https://wpartisan.me/tutorials/wordpress-database-queries-speed-sql_calc_found_rows) updated his code on my request and updated code works 110%.

Bundle of Thanks